# How to send chunked audio data BIng speech rest api js

Tags: javascript, azure, audio, buffer, speech-to-text

I am trying to use Bing speech api from azure , 
I got my subscription key , 
what I can't understand is how to send the audio as a chunked data as the documentation tells in js this is the code that I am using

```
var blob = new Blob(audioChunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000' });
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    reader.onloadend = function() {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
```

and this is the response that I got from the api

```
{"RecognitionStatus":"InitialSilenceTimeout","Offset":19000000,"Duration":0}
```

the response status code is 200 , 
note that I am using the rest api . 
any one could help ? .